# Dropzone.js error: "window is not defined"

Tags: javascript, window, reactjs, dropzone.js, referenceerror

I'm new to Dropzone.js. I did `npm install dropzone` and, in my app, tried loading it with `var DropzoneComponent = require('dropzone')`. However, I get this error each time:

```
[15:50:01] ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myapp/node_modules/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js:1726:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myapp/node_modules/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js:1728:4)
```

I have version 4.0.1, which is the latest release. Google didn't turn up anything for this.

I'm ultimately trying to use Dropzone with React, but this was an error I encountered along the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running that code on the server?

Comment: I just used this react-dropzone component with success: https://github.com/paramaggarwal/react-dropzone . This also looks nice https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component